# Online trading platform

Tags: finance, trading

Does anyone know a good online trading platform for simulation (no to make real money, but just to simulate a P&L) ?
I would like to test myself  as a bank trader (so sell side and not buy side) just to see if I could  be good at it...

I would like to trade vanillas but also exotic with the possibility to have the associated greeks to hedge them with real-time market data.

Does such a platform for simulation (I insist) exist ?

Tx

Comment: I would say that this question is ill-posed. Trading on the sell side means market-making. You can do this with any kind of programming language, but you will need to build a simulation for constantly pricing options (and hedging them) depending on the quantity demanded by the market; using data from a broker in this case will not help you, since you don't have DMA and therefore cannot gauge the supply and demand (and this is usually done by being able to assess the LOB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most brokers have a paper account, try interactive brokers. I am not a bank trader, but I would imagine having the ability to sell options is all you need to play around for a bit? Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

Before starting trading exotic products, You will have to price and get the risk profile (greeks, P&L, Daily P&L). I advise you to use this website that will allow you to price exotic products, calibrate volatilty and many other solutions for Forex, Equities and Basket products:

[Derivatives Management Solution](https://www.valometrics.com)

And once you know how to manage derivatives, you can contact brokers like IB to long or short them depending on your needs.